# Cannot use Sendgrid Java API to send UTF-8 encoded emails

Tags: java, email, encoding, utf-8, sendgrid

I've just switched from Mandrill to Sendgrid. When using the standard Sendgrid JAVA API to send emails the email header content-type is listed as:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

I have not been able to find a way to change this to UTF-8 which is my requirement for sending properly encoded emails. This worked just fine when using Mandrill. Sending via Mandrill kept the original source encoding intact in the content-type header. My current code is basically using this Sendgrid sample code:
https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/v3-java-code-example/

**Environment:**

- JDK 1.8
- sendgrid-java 4.48

My source files are all encoded with UTF-8 and my project is built via Maven with maven-compiler-plugin set to

```
<encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
```

The messsage body that I am posting to Sendgrid is HTML and has the following content-type set in the head element:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

The results of using Sendgrid is that the message gets clipped in Gmail. This seems to be due to the conflicting encoding types. Ie the "mail" header says iso-8859-1 even though the actual content is UTF-8. If I understand this correctly the result is that characters are encoded incorretly.

Note: I'm sending Norwegian characters ÆØÅ.

I've tried to convert the message body to ASCII and iso-8859-1. The results of this is that the email is no longer clipped in Gmail, but the ÆØÅ characters are replaced with questionmarks (I know that US_ASCII does not support the ÆØÅ characters). I've also tried to override the Sendgrid header with this code:

```
mail.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

But that key is reserved and cannot be overriden..

I've also contacted Sendgrid support. They replied with the following:

> Unfortunately, our system will automatically encode the body with
> whatever encoding is being passed to us. This means, that if there are
> characters in that email that are ISO-8859 characters. Then the body
> is going to be using that encoding. We do not currently have an option
> to force UTF-8 encode the body of emails that are being passed through
> us.
>
> Going forward, you would need to convert these emails previous to
> sending them to our servers. Or put a procedure in place to decode
> them into UTF-8 when they are received. For more in depth help with
> code, I would suggest reaching out of the GitHub issue board of the
> language you're using is a great way to gain insight:
> https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-java.

Comment: Still no reply from Sendgrid support. Has anybody else had issues with getting a response from their support team? I've tried multiple channels now and all I get is silence

Comment: I'm running into the very same issue right now. Did you find any viable workaround to avoid e-mails being clipped in Gmail?

Comment: Hi Joshua! No I opted to go for a different vendor in the end. However I finally did get a reply from Sendgrid support. I've appended the reply from support in the original post above

Comment: Thank you! I ended up going with an HTML e-mail in the end, encoding non-ASCII characters as HTML entities. Not great, but did the trick.

Answer (score 5):

As a workaround you can force usage of UTF-8 in HTML email body: add character outside of ISO-8859 charset in comment. For example add:

```
<!-- ™ -->
```

Users won't see it unless they open raw body content.